# "Je suis fini" ou "J'ai fini"?

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes, auxiliaires

> A: You are done eating?
>
> B: Yes, I'm done.

Quelle serait la bonne traduction de ces deux phrases ?

> A: Tu as/es fini de manger ?
>
> B: Oui, je suis fini / j'ai fini.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

« Avoir fini » → to be done, to be finished.

« Être fini » → to be done for, finished with, kaput!

That is, the *fini* you want is the past participle, not the adjective. (And if it's the past participle, the auxiliary is just about always *avoir* unless it's a Dr. Mrs. Vandertramp verb or is reflexive.)

Comment: Yes, avoid *être fini* and *ne pas être fini* when referring to people! *Je suis fini* → "My career is over, I have no future" and *Il n'est pas fini* → "He is a moron"…

Comment: @jlliagre I hadn't heard the negative one! Good to know...

Comment: "Il est fini à la pisse".