# "C'est fini" ou "Ça a fini"?

Tags: verbes, auxiliaires

> A: C'est fini, votre travail ?
>
> B: Oui, c'est fini !

L'utilisation de *c'est fini* est-elle correcte ici ? Ou devrait-on utiliser plutôt *ça a fini* ?

Un autre exemple, avec un sens un peu différent:

> A: Tu n'es plus avec lui ?
>
> B: C'est fini ! Nous avons divorcé.

Cette question sur [Je suis fini/J'ai fini](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25948/je-suis-fini-ou-jai-fini) est similaire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**C'est fini** : on affirme que c'est terminé ou on demande si c'est terminé, sans détail supplémentaire.

**Ça a fini** : on cherche à décrire la fin du processus, en donnant des indications sur par exemple le moment, la manière ou les circonstances de l'arrêt final.

> - Ça a fini peu avant trois heures.
> - Ça a fini brusquement, sans que personne ne s'y soit attendu.
> - Ça a fini dans l'indifférence la plus totale.
> - Ça a fini de détruire leur couple. → La séparation était pressentie, mais elle devint certaine à partir d'un certain évènement (représenté ici par « ça »).

Pourquoi peut-on dire simplement « il a fini », alors que « ça a fini » semble plus rare ? Peut-être que ***ça*** n'est pas habituellement un agent actif. En partant de cette idée, on peut cependant chercher des modèles :

> - *« Ça a fini de sécher »* en parlant de vêtements étendus sur une corde à linge ou de peinture sur des murs ou sur une toile, serait tout à fait convenable.
> - *« Est-ce que ça a fini de calculer ? »* en parlant d'un ordinateur exécutant un programme pourrait, je crois mais sous toute réserve, être acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

La tournure *ça a fini* est dissonante en plus d'avoir un sens précis. Quand on dit *c'est fini*, le pronom *cela* (*c'*) peut représenter à peu près n'importe quoi, et reprend généralement un groupe nominal précédent. Dire *ça a fini*, revient à dire *ça a cessé*, *ça a terminé* ou bien *ça s'est terminé* où le *ça* représente une entité bien définie. Attention toutefois car *ça a fini par + verbe* indique la façon dont une chose s'est terminée, le *par + verbe* est alors un complément circonstanciel de manière.